# Information provided by a bounded series to the underlying sequence

Tags: real-analysis

If a sequence is bounded it does not say anything about the terms of the sequence i.e. convergence of the sequence. But if a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is bounded then it gives information on the terms of the sequence i.e. convergence of the sequence $\{a_n\}$. But it can't say whether it will converge or diverge. Is it correct

Comment: If a series $\sum_n a_n$ is bounded by a radius $ρ$, then the sequence $(a_n)_{n ∈ ℕ}$ is bounded by $2ρ$. It does not need to converge as shown by the series $\sum_n (-1)^n$.

Comment: If the $a_n$ all have the same sign then the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

If a series converges, then the terms in the series must converge to zero. If a series is bounded, then the terms of the series are bounded but the terms of the series may or may not converge. An easy example is the series $1 -1 + 1 -1 + 1 -1 \cdots$.